# Display image in imageview in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've set a `onClickListener` on ImageView layout and trying display the image from phone. Everywhere I looked for the process and most are similar. So it should work but image is not displaying in imageview. Maybe I'm not handling in right way as everything is happening in fragment. In fragment my code for displaying image. I need suggestion to overcome.

```
public class UserProfile extends Fragment {

    private ImageView profileImg;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);
        profileImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_profile);
        profileImg.setOnClickListener(chngImgHandler);
        return v;
    }

    OnClickListener chngImgHandler = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Layout of user profile

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/profilepicBG"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_profile"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangePicture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="You?"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you implement `onActivityResult` in `FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: yes i think so and please see my code

Comment: your parent activity onActivityResult will get called, so you need to put code present in fragment's onActivityResult there ....

Answer (score 0):

Is this an inner class? Because I don't see your declaration for `profileImg` anywhere. Try adding:

```
private ImageView profileImg;
```

..on the very top of the class. Or, if that isn't the case then try adding:

```
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

..to your `onClick` method declaration.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem and that line fixed it for me.

Anyhoo, have you tried using `profileImg.setImageUri(selectedImageUri)` directly inside `onActivityResult`?

Comment: same code is working if i do this in Activity but problem is fragment. I'm not getting it :(